# Faltan componetes de la paleta, como timepiker o chronometer

Tags: android-studio

Estoy empezando con el android studio, uso la versión 3.1.2 y no soy capaz de encontrar componentes de la paleta como timepiker o chronometer.
¿Como los puedo añadir?, ¿es posible conseguir más?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo.
Pues es un fallo del Android Studio.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519550/android-studio-3-1-where-is-the-timepicker-in-the-layout-editor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

La "solución" es meter los elementos a mano editando el texto del xml.